# MultiValueDictKeyError at generated form element

Tags: django, django-forms

This is my form:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-4"> <input type="text" name="ad" placeholder="İsim"> 
     
  {% for question in model.get_questions %}
  <div class="question col-6">
    <div class="header"> {{ question }} <input type="checkbox" name="answ{{forloop.counter0}}"> 
    </div>
  </div>    
  {% endfor %}

  <input type="submit" value="Gönder">
</form>
```

When I try to get `request.POST['ad']` in the views its pretty working but when I try to get like `answ0` it doesnt working. That doesn't appear when I print `request.POST` also. This is the error I receive:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /form/1
'answ0'
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a checkbox is *not* checked, it is simply not part of the request. So if you tick `answ2`, and `answ4`, then `answ0`, `answ1` and `answ3` will *not* be part of the request.

You thus will look at:

```
if 'answ0' in request.POST:
    pass  # 🖘 checked
else:
    pass  # 🖘 not checked
```

Checkboxes are a bit tricky, just like `date` input for example. Therfore typically a [Django **`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/) is typically used at least to validate and clean the input.